# Why is the vector Laplacian defined in a way that only makes sense for three-dimensional vector fields?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definition, vector-fields, laplacian, curl

Both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Vector_Laplacian) and [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorLaplacian.html) define the vector Laplacian of a vector field ${\bf A}$ to be
$$
\nabla^2 {\bf A} := {\bf \nabla} (\nabla \cdot {\bf A}) - \nabla \times (\nabla \times {\bf A}).
$$
This definition only makes sense for vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$, because of the presence of the curls in the second term.

But it seems to me that the alternate, more general definition
$$
(\nabla^2 {\bf A})^j := \partial_i \partial_i A^j
$$
using abstract index notation (which is equivalent for vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$) is much more natural because:

1. It makes the connection to the scalar Laplacian much clearer, thereby motivating the name of the operator.
2. It applies to any vector field on Euclidean space of any dimension - and even more generally, on any Riemannian manifold (if the partial derivatives are promoted to covariant ones). Moreover, this more general operator remains $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ invariant for any dimension of vector space.

Is there any motivation for restricting to the less general (and arguably less intuitive) standard definition?

Comment: It's probably just for familiarity. You may be interested in learning about the Hodge Laplacian: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operators_in_differential_geometry#Hodge_Laplacian

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I guess another benefit of that definition is that by defining the vector Laplacian in terms of more familiar vector derivatives, it makes in clear that the vector Laplacian is rotationally invariant to someone who knows that div, grad, and curl are all rotationally invariant but who isn't familiar with abstract index notation (which is probably a fairly common situation for those first taking multivariable calculus).